# Обтекаемость элементов

Tags: css3, html, css

Никак не могу понять, как можно сделать, чтобы последний блок влез в свободное место, которое выше:

[image]

Стиль каждого блока:

```
.list-item
{
  margin-left: .6%;
  max-width: 400px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  padding: 0 1%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 47%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант
http://jsfiddle.net/doz5b93d/

or

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: фига се, бутстрап и такое умеет :)

Comment: Понял, что с этой фишкой, IE будет проходить мимо(. Спасибо, буду по-другому выводить, в один столбец)

Answer (score 0):

Ни как кроме, как ни поставив ему (блоку) абсолютное позиционирование

Comment: да что ж вы всё не уймётесь со своим абсолютным позиционированием :) это адресовато не лично вам, а по мотивам [этого вопроса][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/411883/